# Creating javascript functions when needed

Tags: javascript, performance

I'm trying to determine the performance implications of some javascript. In our application, a form contains a number of widgets. Not all widgets are used on every page or a widget might be used more than once. I've been thinking about a model similar to the following (note that the actual script is a lot more complicated, I've simplified it to be brief):

```
var widget = {
    type1: function(args) {
        function getName() {
            return this._name;
        }
        return (widget.type1 = function(args) {
            return {
                _name: args.name,
                getName: getName
            };
        })(args);
    }
}
```

My thought is that the first time the `widget.type1` function is called, it will initialize all the code needed for a widget.type1. Any subsequent widget.type1 would then use the functions. I know that I could do something like this:

```
var widget = {
    type1: function(args) {
        return {
            _name: args.name,
            getName: function getName() {
                return this._name;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

But then each type1 object would have it's own copy of a function that does the same thing, which I would assume would use more memory (I've tested in browser debugging tools that o1.getName != o2.getName).

I could just write out the script for the types of widgets that are on the current page from the server, but then I don't benefit from caching a single js file and I don't want to put each widget in its own js file because then it would have to download them all separately.

Will this result in problems? Would/should this perform as I think? Other thoughts?

*Edit*

I think I should explain my reasoning. My thought (which could be erroneous) is that the first time a widget is used, it would initialize the logic used by the widget. For instance, if I never create a type1 widget, there's no need to add a bunch of functions to the prototype of the type1 widget. The code I wrote was *highly* simplified. There may be 500+ lines of code used by that widget, and I'm not actually using a getName function, that was just an example. If the widget isn't used, it wouldn't need that logic at all. It also keeps functions only used by that widget out of the global scope.

I'm currently using objects and adding functions to the prototype of that object (e.g. `MyType.prototype.whatever = function(){ ... }`), but the thought occurred to me that if I never create an object of `MyType`, why bother initializing the prototype of `MyType`?

Another way to do what I'm thinking, this time using object prototypes (again, there might be 300 functions added to the prototype of type1. The idea I'm asking is if it makes any sense at all to not go ahead and add them to the prototype of type1 if a type1 is never created):

```
var widget = {
    _type1Init: function()
    {
        widget.type1.prototype.getName = function() {
            return this._name;
        }
        widget._type1Init = function(){}    //So calling again won't do anything.
    },
    type1: function(args) {
        widget._type1Init();
        this._name = args.name;
    }
}
if(*someCondition*)
    var obj = new widget.type1({ name: "hello world" });    // If an object is created, it gets initilized, otherwise it won't.
```

Comment: The second snippet is better. You should realize youre going to be creating a function wrapping `_name` in both cases but in the second one you have an unnecessary seaf which does not accomplish anything (your `getName` helper is still created whenever you do `widget.type1`

Comment: If you want instance based code you should consider Constructors, or `Object.create()` and its backward compatible counterpart.

Comment: Computers have gigabytes of memory, worrying about a few bytes is not worth the effort. Writing code that is simple to understand and easy to maintain is of far more value. If you want to share methods among objects, use prototype inheritance.

Comment: But where will the content of other functions be? inside another function? commented out? in one large Object?

Comment: So what approach did you take?

Comment: I've edited the original post to make it more clear what I'm asking. It's a question of whether or not the script inside the function will get parsed, stored in memory, use processor cycles, etc if the function is never called. E.g. if I never create a type1 widget, why bother adding a bunch of functions to widget.type1.prototype?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should consider:

```
function type1(argObj){
  // use arguments Array for all arguments - you have Object notation
  this._name = argObj.name;
  // not sure why you need this function
  this.getName = function(){
    return this._name;
  }
}
function widget(){
  this.type1 = type1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you want to achieve, but I think this is a case for [`prototype`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain#With_a_constructor)

```js
var widget = {
    type1: function(args) {
        this._name = args.name;
    }
};

widget.type1.prototype.getName = function() {
    return this._name;
}

var w1 = new widget.type1({ name: 'Alice' });
console.log(w1.getName());
var w2 = new widget.type1({ name: 'Bob' });
console.log(w2.getName());
```

See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z566J/)

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'd consider... not necessarily a whole restructure, but if your module/widget has:

a) known "private static" functions (utilities or stateless transformers) that you want to reuse
  b) functions which must operate on instance-specific state

Then you're in the market for an IIFE.

```
{
    widget_1 : (function () {
        var private_static_method = function (a, b, c) {
            }; // no access to instance-based, closure state, unless passed as arguments

        return function (d, e, f) {
            // d, e and f are currently private, instance-based values (closure-scope)
            this.public_method = function () { // this is copied per-instance
                // has full access to d, e, f
                return private_static_function(d, e, f);
            };
            this.g = d;
        };
    }())
}
```

`widget_1` is the returned function.
The constructor which is `widget_1` now has private-static access (closure) to whatever is INSIDE the wrapping function, but OUTSIDE of the constructor.

So there's only one copy, with the caveat that the static functions have *no* sight into any private state (closure) of any instance.

Moreover, taking this one step further would indeed allow you to break up your JS into individual files (which you could build back into one file safely) and have your object work exactly the same way on the other side.

```
// core-file.js
var my_widgets = {};

// widget-1.js
(function (core) {
    var private_static_method = function () { };
    // ...
    core.widget_1 = function (d, e, f) { };
}(my_widgets));
```

You can then recombine all of your files and access them just like before, on the other side.

```
var widget_1a = new my_widgets.widget_1(a, b, c);
```

If you have *absolutely no* private state, then rather than the "private static" stuff above, what you can do inside of your IIFE is define a constructor function, and add prototypes to it (these are "public-static", with *no* access to private state).

```
widget_1 : (function () {
    var Widget_1 = function (d, e, f) { this.g = d; };
    Widget_1.prototype.add_one = function () { this.g += 1; };
    return Widget_1;
)())

var w1 = new my_widgets.widget_1(x, y, z);
w1.add_one();
w1.g; // == x+1
```

A combination of enclosed utility functions, enclosed per-instance state, extended prototype functions, et cetera, will allow you to do everything you want, from lowering memory-footprint (I hope you have thousands of these before worrying about this), to chaining together super-secure (higher-memory-usage) objects.

**note** although doing crazy closure stuff might be secure, client-side code (or, more-especially, the http(s?) bridge between the worlds is very much not...

Answer (score 0):

If a widget is used more than once, than the object/prototype model will conserve memory.

something like this:

```
var wid = {}

wid.objInit=function(p) { this.p=p }  
wid.objInit.prototype.doit=function(){ return this.p + ' it'}

wid.init=function(arg){
  var w = new wid.objInit(arg)
  return w
}
```

The prototype is written once, placed into memory once and each object instance can call it.

```
var w = wid.init('do')
console.log( w.doit() )

var w2 = wid.init('do')
console.log( w2.doit() )
```